# How to make a Field as searchable in Global search

Tags: search, global-search

I have a Field called Employees( Text Field) on Account object. I want to make a field as searchable. I have created a workflow and I have added a field to search layouts as well, but no luck. Can anyone help me on this

Answer (score 1):

As per documentation, searchable fields for account object is supported in lightning experience

[image]

Check details of Searchable Fields by Object for [Classic](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=search_fields_cex.htm&type=5) and [Lightning](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=search_fields_lex.htm&type=5) here

Thanks